# Multiple instances of the same class getting same event from event bus

Tags: java, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I am using greenroot eventbus to pass event payloads between the 2 components of my application in an async manner using the **@Subscribe** annotation to subscribe to events.
The issue is if multiple instances of the class having **@Subscribe** annotation are registered with the event bus, 
All of them receive the same event payload and the computation is done multiple times.(As many instances i have created.)

Is there a way for the event bus to provide the event payload to only a single instance of my class i.e

If my subscribe method looks like:

```
public class A {

 A() {
   eventBus.register(this);
 }

 @Subscribe
public void consumeEvent(String s) {
   // do something
}

}
```

If i create 5 instances of class A, and pass 5 strings to the eventbus, all of the subscribed instances should get 1 instance each.

Is there a way i can avoid this redundant computation because of multiple objects?.